# Flex3 - action script : How to capture the emptyness of an Array of Object

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I would like to know when an Array of objects is empty (or not).

I tried using the ObjectProxy as follow:

```
myArrayProxy=new ObjectProxy(myArray);
myArrayProxy.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, changeArrayHandler)
```

But the event is not fired when the object's content change.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) and listen to the [collectionChange](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#event%3acollectionChange) event.